# Sort teams by average vote for a given jury

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following schema :

```
teams(id, name)
jury(id, name)
criteria(id, name, coefficient, jury_id)
vote(id, team_id, jury_id, value, criterion_id)
```

I would like to get every team and order them by average vote for a given jury.

Here is my current SQL:

```
SELECT teams.*, 
  SUM(votes.value * criteria.coefficient) / SUM(criteria.coefficient) AS rating 
  FROM "teams" 
  LEFT JOIN "votes" ON "teams"."id" = "votes"."team_id" 
  LEFT JOIN "criteria" ON "votes"."criterion_id" = "criteria"."id" 
  WHERE (votes.jury_id = 3510 OR votes.jury_id IS NULL)
  GROUP BY teams.id
  ORDER BY rating DESC NULLS LAST, teams.id
```

This works well for the following cases:

- The team as vote for the selected jury
- The team as vote for the selected jury and for other jury (the vote for other jury is not taken into account)
- The team as no vote at all (the team appears at the end of the list)

It DOES NOT work for the following case:

- The team is voted for another jury but not on the selected jury (in this case, the team does not appear in the list)

How could I make this work.

Comment: have you tried to add isnull(SUM(votes.value * criteria.coefficient) / SUM(criteria.coefficient),0) AS rating, in addition to that filtering the table votes enforces inner join so it is better to use sub query.

Comment: "The team is voted for another jury but not on the selected jury " because in your clause you say that  if juryId=3510 or null... :/ try to remove that....

Comment: The problem is that any team with vote for other juries but not the current one is not selected because of the where clause : `WHERE (votes.jury_id = 3510 OR votes.jury_id IS NULL)`. In this case there won't be a team row with NULL vote values but a team row with vote concerning another jury, so it will be filtered by the WHERE clause.

Comment: @AndreeaDumitru The problem is in fact trying to remove that as you said

Comment: you can remove the filter and caluclate the average vote for only the given jury  by using case when votes.jury_id = 3510 then sum(....) else 0 end.

Comment: @Boody Tried `CASE WHEN votes.jury_id=3526 THEN (SUM(votes.value * criteria.coefficient) / SUM(criteria.coefficient)) ELSE 0 END)` but I cannot do this, because column "votes.jury_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

Comment: Then, you can add union query to get all other missing teams with 0 as rating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came with the following SQL:

```
SELECT "teams".* 
  FROM (
    SELECT teams.*, SUM(votes.value * criteria.coefficient) / SUM(criteria.coefficient) AS rating, teams.id 
      FROM "teams" 
      LEFT JOIN "votes" ON "teams"."id" = "votes"."team_id"
      LEFT JOIN "criteria" ON "votes"."criterion_id" = "criteria"."id" 
      WHERE (votes.jury_id = 3613 OR votes.jury_id IS NULL)
      GROUP BY teams.id 
  UNION
    SELECT teams.*, NULL AS rating, teams.id
      FROM "teams"
      INNER JOIN "votes" ON "votes"."team_id" = "teams"."id"
      INNER JOIN "criteria" ON "criteria"."id" = "votes"."criterion_id"
      GROUP BY teams.id HAVING EVERY(votes.jury_id != 3613)
  ) AS teams
  ORDER BY rating DESC NULLS LAST, teams.created_at
```

However, I could not sort on teams.id because it says the column in ambiguous. I tried replacing 'AS teams' with another alias without success so I used another column `created_at` instead.